# too few arguments with scaffold code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

The `join` method below in the teams_controller.rb is sent the following data through submission of a form using EmberJs

```
{"id"=>"3", "user_id"=>"42", "action"=>"join", "controller"=>"teams"}
```

The record is getting created with the `join` method below (according to the console), but the code for what happens after the `save` is throwing an error

```
ArgumentError (too few arguments):
  app/controllers/teams_controller.rb:145:in `format'
  app/controllers/teams_controller.rb:145:in `join'
```

I copied the code following the `@team.save` method from the Rails scaffold generator, so I'm a little surprised.  The hope is that it will respond with the json, but I left in the html format `just because` (maybe there's a graceful degradation benefit). Can you tell me why that error's being thrown and/or how I could avoid it?

Rails method

```
  def join

    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    id = params[:user_id]
    @team.user_ids =  @team.user_ids.push(id)


   if @team.save
    format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Joined Team' }
    format.json { render json: @team, status: :created, location: @team }
   else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end

  end
```

Update,
I should also note that, based on the line number of the error message, the method seems to be treating the format as html, however, I wanted it to be treated as json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to put respond_to do |format| around the code.

```
 respond_to do |format|

  if @team.save
    format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Joined Team' }
    format.json { render json: @team, status: :created, location: @team }
   else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end


 end
```